# How to add cc, tailor-made sender name and fetch data for subject line in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Apps Script. I am wondering how can I add a cc inside this script?

Meanwhile, when the email is sent, the receiver will see my name as (e.g. peter.henderson), would that be possible if I change it to Peter Henderson?

For the subject line, I would like to fetch people's name. So that would be something like "Thank you for your interest, NAME!" How can I do that?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var whatisyourname = e.values[2];
  var email = e.values[1];

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("followupemailtemplate");
  template.name = whatisyourname;
  template.evaluate

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,
                    "Thank you for your interest!",
                    "",
                    {htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent() });
}
```

Comment: Look in the other options besides htmlBody.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Use the advanced parameter `name` to set a sender name, `cc` to CC someone to the email, and a template literal to insert the entered name into the subject.*

#### Example:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const email = e.values[1]
  const name = e.values[2]
  const subject = `Thank you for your interest, ${name}`
  const body = "Some non-HTML body content"

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("followupemailtemplate")
  template.name = name
  template.evaluate()

  const options = {
    htmlBody: template.getContent(),
    cc: "someemail@cclandia.com",
    name: "Peter Henderson"
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, options)
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class MailApp - `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` - Advanced Parameters | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters_1)